# Does beep over SSH work when root?

Tags: root-access, ssh

I tried running a busybox version of `beep` over SSH but recieved the following error message:

```
$ beep                                                                
beep: can't open console
$ ls -l /dev/console                                                  
crw-------    1 root     root        5,   1 Jun 22 23:32 /dev/console
```

If I were to invest the time in rooting my device would this work? I imagine that this may not be the only complication...

Comment: To add further more info, I tried this command with root privileges, got the same error. Don't know what it is but thought I should add my part.

Comment: I can't believe no one up voted this question ,it is a serious question even if the asker never came back to see an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time of reflection and a good night sleep ,I came back to edit my answer.

#### Short answer:

`beep` will not work under Android as Android devices do not have an internal system speaker and no kernel module `pcspkr`. I tried to beep old school way with the command `echo -en "\a" > /dev/tty5`, but it will not work since Android doesn't have an internal speaker.

Whenever I run `beep` with root or without it always return the same error:

```
   beep : can't open console
```

After reading the beep documentation I think the problem is not that you don't have permission – but due to `beep` command not finding the console (for info: `beep` will use `tty0` as default console to beep and not the `/dev/console`) and that's why it returns "can't open console" and not "permission denied". To fix this you would need to compile `beep` from busybox source with option to change the default console like in the `beep` desktop version.

#### But nothing is impossible you can make your own beep program easily following this steps :

- make sure you have the binary `aplay` on your phone have it under `/system/bin` it is used by the system to play boot sounds if you don't have it grab the arm version from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/om6xrwfgb8h3vqa/aplay?dl=0) and put it under `/system/bin` on your phone and give it the right permission it have to be executable.
- download this `beep.wav` file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/monpiypo9800jb9/beep.wav.zip?dl=0) and put it somewhere on the system partition of the phone or any where else your choice in my exemple it will be `/system/beep.wav`.
- now you can either beep usin this command

  ```
  aplay /system/beep.wav
  ```

  or you can make a script file name it beep and put it under `/system/xbin` or `/system/bin` you can either over right or rename the old copy since it is just a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to the busybox binary. You can always call the original beep by `busybox beep` command and don't forget to give it the execute permission.

Here is the simple exemple of the script to write:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
aplay /system/beep.wav
```

This will beep your device with the current default speaker it can be the phone's speaker, headset or Bluetooth headset, you can change that using the aplay option `-Dnameofpcmdevice`

This script can only beep once but, I see many possibilities can be added easily, like playing other sounds alarm and adding arguments like frequency – and much more.

externel links reference and assets :

http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep

http://www.soundjay.com/beep-sounds-1.html

http://media.io/ >> great online service to convert sounds to wav format supported by aplay

I hope this will solve your problem or at least give you an alternative

Comment: @LôrdRalfAdolf May I still ask if you verified what you wrote *on an Android device* (and if so, on which)? Neither me nor Firelord were able to have that "work just fine", but both got the same error: "beep: can't open console" in all cases (via `adb shell`, via `ssh`, and via local terminal).

Comment: I can confirm what Izzy and firelord said ,the command beep return can't open console even with root ,tested on HTC one with CyanogenMod on local terminal ,adb shell and ssh

Comment: @Izzy I updated my answer with a proper explanation of the beep binary and what may be causing this issue ,but I can be wrong :D please read and tell me what you think

Comment: I cannot verify currently, but it sounds great now (I've just applied a little formatting, hope you don't mind ;) Now let's wait for the OP who is likely to have the urge of verification :) Thanks a lot for all your effort. That alone is worth an upvote: though I cannot really "try it out", it seems sound to me. Great you don't only say `beep` doesn't work, even explain why – but also include a way to "fake" it. Good job I'd say!

Comment: Thanks @Izzy I don't mind the edit ,I appreciate it ,I know I am not getting any spell or text formatting awards any time soon ,I will try my best next time to save you the trouble

Comment: If you can, that's fine of course. If not, I'm there again, no probs :)